# How to call css in before closing body tag in magento

Tags: magento

Call `css` in before closing `body` tag in magento everytime it
 will show error,I added all `js` in before body tag closed but when I try to add `css` it will show error?

> **1st method=> js and css not working and showing error**

```
local.xml       
 <reference name="before_body_end">
   <block type="core/template" name="footer_js" template="footer/js.phtml">
       <action method="additem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/abc.css</name></action> 
       <action method="additem"> <type>skin_js</type> <name>js/share_button.js</name></action         
   </block>
 </reference>


footer/js.phtml

<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>

2col.phtml=> before closing body tag

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_js') ?>
```

> **2nd method
>     js working bt css not, no error**

```
local.xml

<reference name="before_body_end">
   <block type="core/template" name="footer_js" template="footer/js.phtml"/>
   </reference>

 footer/js.phtml
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js')  ?>"></script>

<link href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/negi.css')?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

 2col.phtml=> before closing body tag

 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_js') ?>
```

Comment: can you post your code and error you are getting ?

Comment: can u pls tell me what is going wrong on this code ????

Comment: do you have link to share your site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a block with the name before_body_end where you can add everything you want with template or text block.

You need something like this, you have no page/html_head block to refer too:

```
<!-- get the block which we want our content in -->
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <!-- add another block of type page/html_head to have all the great functionality to add/remove css and js stuff -->
    <!-- it is important to set your own template, because the head block has a defined default template page/head.phtml which has all the stuff of the head. Using this will bring a lot of problems -->
    <block type="page/html_head" name="scripts_in_footer" template="YOUR TEMPLATE">
        <!-- add whatever you want as you are used to in the head via the standard magento api -->
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

And inside of your template, you need:

```
<?php // and to echo the whole stuff later in the template, you need to add the code, so the added js/Css files are echoed ?>
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```

Comment: pls somebody help i m stuck

Comment: again not working and also with error, bt thanx for ur supprot

Comment: silly mistake it is not before_body_ends it is before_body_end  thanks arunendra....ur previous answer is working..bt this answer is not working...

Comment: @Rahul negi i have posted my previous answer feel free to accept it.

Comment: @jibin it might help you https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html

Answer (score 1):

**local.xml**

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
           <!-- add another block of type page/html_head to have all the great functionality to add/remove css and js stuff -->
           <!-- it is important to set your own template, because the head block has a defined default template page/head.phtml which has all the stuff of the head. Using this will bring a lot of problems -->
           <block type="page/html_head" name="abc" template="footer/abc.phtml">
               <!-- add whatever you want as you are used to in the head via the standard magento api -->
               <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/negi.css</name></action>
           </block>
       </reference>
```

**Yourtheme/template/footer/abc.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```

**2col.phtml=> before closing body tag**

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('abc') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <remove name="right.poll"/>
        <reference name="head">
          <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/owl.theme.css</stylesheet></action>
          <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/owl.carousel.css</stylesheet></action>
          <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/bootstrap.min.css</stylesheet></action>
          <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/font-awesome.min.css</stylesheet></action>
          <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom-style.css</stylesheet></action>

          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/bootstrap.min.js</name></action>
           <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/responsive-accordion.min.js</name></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/responsiveCarousel.min.js</name></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.hammer.min.js</name></action>
          <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/custom.js</name></action> 
           <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700</href></action>
           <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,900,800,700,600,300</href></action>
          <!--Remove CSS and JS, skin Folder-->
           <!--action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name></action-->

        </reference>
    </default>
```

Comment: what is this i m talking about  how to add css before closing body tag not in head?????

Comment: Simply you add this using 
<link style="" href="$this->skinUrl()/css/yourcss.css" />

 Add this before body where you want this in page.

Comment: There are no other way Rahul. If we include it in local.xml then it adding in head tag. so you can add it like above.

Comment: i m also calling css from js.phtml ...<link href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/abc.css')?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> ...not working as well... bt at the same time js is also calling from js.phtml its working bt css not????